# Practical effects of Torchship-strength Magnetic Nozzles

Tags: science-based, spaceships, electromagnetism

In a sci-fi universe with high-end interplanetary torchship technology (think the Expanse), high-speed space travel is normalized, with ships of all sizes regularly traveling between planets on the backs of extremely powerful engines, utilizing the forces of nuclear fusion to propel themselves at 1G for days or weeks at a time.

These engines exploit the same forces that can wipe cities off the map, and thus would easily destroy most conventional nozzle technologies. As such, one of the essential technologies for such an engine would also have to be a magnetic nozzle, powerful enough to curve the forces of essentially a continuous nuclear explosion away from the ship. And then, being a magnetic field, the lines of force from this nozzle will continue on past the engine, curling around the sides of the ship until eventually making their way back to the front of the engine. The ship proper would be encased in a faraday cage assembly, to prevent any sort of unwanted effects inside the ship.

What I'm curious about is what effect would such an extreme field have outside of the engine, in both the context of regular commerce and combat.

- How would it react with anything metallic, such space debris or small iron meteoroid? Would they get "sucked" back into wherever the magnetic field re-enters the engine, potentially impacting the hull in the process?
- What affect would it have on humans outside the faraday cage, such as someone in a spacesuit doing maintenance on the hull? Assume the actual fusion torch is off.
- Would these fields have a visible aurora, either from stray engine particles or external sources like other engines or the sun?
- Could you use the same field to curve in a metallic droplet radiator or would it be too extreme/close to the engine/etc?
- What affect would these fields have on particle or laser emissions from enemy weaponry? I assume macroscopic projectiles would be moving fast enough to be minimally affected.
- Any other cool side-effects you could think of?

For sake of calculation lets assume these nozzles are operating at their extreme; in which they are controlling a fusion torch propelling something the size of a corvette at 10G with only minimal damage to the physical nozzle (survivability of the crew non-withstanding).

Comment: (1) Faraday cages block *variable* electromagnetic fields. They have no effect on constant magnetic fields. (2) The vast majority of metals interact very weakly with magnetic fields, not really more strongly than water does. Ferromagnetism is a rather rare property which occurs in few substances, mostly iron, nickel, cobalt, and some but not all of their alloys. (3) Magnetic fields do not interact with electromagnetic waves, such as light, be it laser light or candle light. (4) The minus one is for magnetic thingy curving "forces". (5) This site wants only one question per question.

Comment: Why would these magnetic fields extend significant;'y beyond the engine? Consider the various magnetic fusion condiment systems, they concentrate the fields where needed,. Top magnetic strength is going to be in the low tens of tesla at best. This is due to current known materials strengths.  Tens of tesla is very similar to current MRI machines(~5T).

Comment: If in fact the field did extend around the entire craft, and depending on the field strength, it could help with a good deal of the solar radiation and particle beam weaponry.

Comment: @Gillgamesh for really high-energy beams (like, the near-lightspeed weaponized ones) bending the beam away is kinda useless because the charged particles just dump much of their energy as Bremsstrahlung radiation (x-rays) in the original direction of travel.

Comment: @BMF agreed, not 100% effective.  Better than zero however.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid generating heat by having a coherent nuclear reaction.

Purify a nuclear isotope that decays by emitting neutrons, and crystalline it. This is an inverted population level, like a laser - the nuclei all want to decay but there is a kinetic barrier to doing so. Cool it to a few millikelvin. Add a couple of Tesla of magnetic field. This would be strong enough to align the nuclear spins. This would mean an incoming neutron might  be amplified by causing nuclear decays in the other atoms it meets. If you align the magnetic field with the crystalline lattice, then the greatest amplification will happen along the densely-packed directions. If you aligned it carefully enough, the amplification would be encouraged by being focussed along the lines of nucleic by the weak nuclear force.

It is not quite as easy (hah!) as that. The nuclear decays could go forwards, or backwards, or in a cone at an angle depending on the other decay products and the conservation of momentum. The forwards and backwards directions are the only ones that get the weak nuclear force focussing, so they are the only ones we need to worry about. So, to avoid a back-pulse, we need the neutron equivalent of a Pockels cell in a high-power laser. Maybe the heating of the crystal as the pulse travels down will dampen the back-pulse. Maybe the magnetic field could be align in some region that travels down the crystal.

Perhaps that's what dilithium crystals do. But they aren't available I the shops yet.